# How can i add quotes around each words stored in a variable in shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I have a variable foo.

echo "print foo" "$foo" ---> abc,bc,cde

I wanted to put quotes around each variable.

Expected result = `'abc','bc','cde'`.

I have tried this way, but its not working:

```
join_lines() {
  local IFS=${1:-,}
  set --
  while IFS= read -r line; do set -- "$@" "$'line'"; done
  echo "$*"
}
```

Comment: On SO its encouraged for users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems in their question, so please do add the same and let us know then.

Comment: `$foo = a,b,c` is invalid shell line. `before each variable` so you want to do `'foo`? `a` `b` and `c` seem to be _characters_ inside a string, not _variables_ and you seem to want to put quotes _around_, not _before_.

Comment: try something like this `echo $foo | sed -e "s/([a-zA-Z]+)/'\1'/g"` (not tested)

Comment: Its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, strictly written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

***Without loop:***

```
var="abc,bc,cde"
echo "$var" | awk -v s1="'" 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="\047,\047"} {$1=$1;$0=s1 $0 s1} 1'
```

***With loop usual way to go through all fields(comma separated):***

```
var="abc,bc,cde"
echo "$var" | awk -v s1="'" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=s1 $i s1}} 1'
```

Output will be `'abc','bc','cde'`.

Comment: Also, i tried adding this in a variable like below:                                                                       
                                                                                                                       
 check="${"$var" | awk -v s1="'" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=s1 $i s1}} 1'}"                                                                                                                                                         but it's throwing error

Comment: @Princy, Both solutions worked for me, kindly copy/paste solution correctly and let  me know then?

Comment: It is working, but i wanted to store the result/outcome in a variable. So I did like below :      check="${"$var" | awk -v s1="'" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=s1 $i s1}} 1'}"

Comment: @Princy, no to take this into a variable do like: `check=$(echo "$var" | awk -v s1="'" 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="\047,\047"} {$1=$1;$0=s1 $0 s1} 1')` OR `check=$(echo "$var" | awk -v s1="'" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=s1 $i s1}} 1')` this should do the trick, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, using 'sed`: replacing every` '`with`'`'`, and adding `'` at the beginning and end of the line to wrap the first/last tokens.

```
sed -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/$/'/" -e "s/,/','/g"
```

Answer (score 0):

On surface, the question is on how to convert comma separated list of values (stored in a shell variable) into a comma separate list of quoted tokens. Extending the logic provided by OP, but using shell arrays

```
foo="abc,bc,cde"
IFS=, read -a items <<< "$foo"
result=
for r in "${items[@]}" ; do
    [ "$result" ] && result+=","
    result+="'$r'"
done
echo "RESULT=$result"
```

If needed, logic can be placed into a function/filter

```
function join_lines {
    local -a items
    local input result
    while IFS=, read -a items ; do
        result=
        for r in "${items[@]}" ; do
            [ "$result" ] && result+=","
            result+="'$r'"
        done
        echo "$result"
    done
}
```

Comment: It had added quotes, but it is only giving me one result.

Comment: in this case, I am only getting 'abc'

Comment: Are you using "bash" - under bash I get `RESULT='abc','bc','cde'`

Comment: Yes I am using, Let me try it again

Comment: Hi, Its working .. but in my variable there are also values with spaces. for eg:                             foo="abc cde xyz , cde efg"                                                                                                                     Expected result is : 'abc cde xyz', 'cde efg'                                                                             but using this I am getting like : 'abc','cde','xyz'... this is incorrect

Comment: Solution revised to support embedded while spaces, by quoting `"${items[@]}", It will not return `RESULT='abc cde xyz ',' cde efg'`